# Windows function ReadFile() too slow

Tags: c, performance, serial-port, readfile

I'm currently developing a project in C which consist to receive data from a usb connection with UART protocol.
In my program to receive the data, i use the function readfile() of windows.h and it works but it's too slow.

Is there another way to do this faster ?

This is my current code:

```
 if(ReadCOM(buffer, sizeof(buffer)-1, &nBytesRead)){
//Data processing
}


BOOL ReadCOM(void* buffer, int nBytesToRead, int* pBytesRead)
{
return ReadFile(g_hCOM, buffer, nBytesToRead, pBytesRead, NULL);
}
```

Thanks for all

Comment: What performance do you get (in Mb/s) and what version of the USB standard are you testing on (USB 2.0 or 3.0)?

Comment: I perform on 9600 Bauds (Bits/S) and i use USB 3.0.
I can't increase baudrates because if i do it, data are not receive correctly

Comment: Sounds like the limit/problem is with the bitrate and not with `Readfile`.

Comment: I use Easypic V7 board of MikroElektronica

Comment: 9600 baud limit?  I have never seen any problem with rates up to 115k on Windows either with 'real' serial ports of USB emulators.